# In what cases would one need to use embedded linux or a kernel on a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, linux

I have already written bare metal software and used FreeRTOS on embedded devices. But I would like to understand why some people choose to use embedded linux or a kernel on an embedded device?
In what cases would it e.g. be unavoidable that you need to use embedded linux or a kernel on an embedded device. How would one come to the conclusion that he needs one of those two things?

Comment: For example when you have to implement a complex functionality which is already implemented on Linux...

Comment: Because sometimes people don't feel like rewriting advanced filesystem support, a full TCP/IP stack, the USB stack, various hardware drivers, mutexes, threads, process management, a powerful shell, a shitload of libraries that can do anything, etc... Yeah, people are lazy, aren't they? Note, it is *never* unavoidable to use that, though. It is just much more efficient in a number of situations.

Comment: Also multi-processing.

Comment: @dim, your glib description doesn't talk about on (a) the downsides of putting that mountain of software you listed onto an embedded microcontroller or (b) how you'd fit it into a device with small flash and RAM - could you balance out your comment? Otherwise it's just a wish list.

Comment: @tonym of course there are downsides. A lot (huge hardware requirement, you don't control how things are done, not really suited for real time, slower boot time, ...) But the question was: "why would you want to use Linux in an embedded environment", as if it made no sense to do so. So I didn't address the "why would you not" part, since OP seemed to have reasons on that side already.

Comment: @dim, I saw 'no sense' bit in the OP post but the two answers posted so far answer it well so looks like they read it like me . Have you put Linux on small embedded MCUs a lot then, you make it sound easy for novices?

Comment: @TonyM Indeed, both answers are focusing on *small* MCUs, but embedded does not necessarily mean small. LPC32xx, for example, is adverstised as a MCU and can support a full-blown linux. A linux Board Support Package is available from NXP, supporting most peripherals, if not all. But I didn't say it was easy for novices either, even if it is certainly easier than redeveloping the whole thing, *if you need an equivalent*. I don't really get where you want to lead me, though. And, regarding my legitimacy to assert such things, I have none. I'm just pretending to be knowledgeable, here.

Answer (score 8):

Generally you wouldn't use a operating system on something that is performing true microcontroller tasks.  In such cases, the OS gets in the way more than it helps.  OSs are about virtualizing hardware resources and providing abstractions like threads and processes.  These things are of little use when the hardware you are driving is easy to control directly, there is no issue of portability, and isn't the kind of thing OSs virtualize for you anyway.  General purpose OSs also don't handle real time requirements well, or at all, and that is something often important in true controller applications.

The reason you do sometimes see operating systems on high end microcontrollers is because those processors are really being used as embedded computers, not really controllers.  When you want to connect to a standard keyboard, mouse, drive a standard display, connect to a network, be a USB host, store files in a arbitrary tree structure, or do any of the other things OSs are intended to help with, then a OS can be helpful.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, it would be interesting to know what you object to.

Answer (score 0):

Linux on microcontrollers? Only using versions with no MMU (Memory Management Unit) - ex. uC Linux. Cortex-M (M - microcontroller) has MPU (Memory Protection Unit). Cortex-A (A - application) has MMU. Usually microprocessors did not incorporate ordinary peripherals found in common microcontrollers. Although very fast, run both the operating system and the user applications. They do not handle very well I/O pins and protocols that demand low **latency**, but are ideal for handling images, audio and transfer of megabytes of data in high **throughput** (USB, Ethernet, etc.). A Raspberry-PI is good for watching a movie, but it is not suitable for implememting FOC control of a three-phase motor, for example. For reasons similar to those already discussed, it is not uncommon to find solutions involving a board with two processors: A Cortex-A running Linux and a Cortex-M in charge of critical tasks (example UDOO board). The BeagleBone is slightly different when included in the same chip, dedicated control and timing peripherals.

Comment: Your examples are far enough apart to be clearly distinct, but today's world is a bit more blurred.  Consider that you can find smart plugs done micro-controller-style with an ESP8266, and others at competitive prices based on inexpensive Linux-based wifi router SoC's.  Effectively, there exists a set of applications that is an overlap between what you can build a "simple" system up to handle, and what you can strip a "complex" one down to fit.